# Как переименовать общие папки в Линуксе с русского на английский?

Tags: linux

Установил, к примеру Убунту на русском. Все папки на кириллице. Установил на английском, папки на латинице. Есть ли такая настройка или процедура переименования папок на латиницу при установке системы на русском. Для того, чтобы из терминала не переключаться на русскую раскладку когда шаришься по файлам(не вводить на русском).

Answer (score 4):

Проверял на Xubuntu, но на обычной убунте тоже должно работать.

Здесь я использую имена папок, начинающиеся с `.`, чтобы они не попадали под шальной `rm -rf ⁎` в папке пользователя. Если для это вас неудобно, то пишите без точек.

1. На всякий случай убираем из автозагрузки `xdg-user-dirs-update` и `xdg-user-dirs-gtk-update`, которые отвечают за автоматическое переименование папок пользователя под локаль.

   В Xubuntu это можно сделать из гуи, про обычную убунту не уверен.

   Можно попробовать пропустить этот шаг, а если папки сами переименуются обратно, то начинать думать.
2. Перемещаем папки:

   ```
   mv 'Рабочий стол' .desktop
   mv 'Загрузки' .downloads
   mv 'Шаблоны' .templates
   mv 'Общедоступные' .shared
   mv 'Документы' .documents
   mv 'Музыка' .music
   mv 'Изображения' .images
   mv 'Видео' .videos
   ```
3. Обновляем пути до папок. Для этого редактируем `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` и пишем туда:

   ```
   XDG_DESKTOP_DIR="$HOME/.desktop"
   XDG_DOWNLOAD_DIR="$HOME/.downloads"
   XDG_TEMPLATES_DIR="$HOME/.templates"
   XDG_PUBLICSHARE_DIR="$HOME/.shared"
   XDG_DOCUMENTS_DIR="$HOME/.documents"
   XDG_MUSIC_DIR="$HOME/.music"
   XDG_PICTURES_DIR="$HOME/.images"
   XDG_VIDEOS_DIR="$HOME/.videos"
   ```
4. Обновляем закладки проводника. Для этого редактируем `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` и пишем туда что-то типа:

   ```
   file:///home/holyblackcat/.documents Документы
   file:///home/holyblackcat/.images Изображения
   file:///home/holyblackcat/.music Музыка
   file:///home/holyblackcat/.videos Видео
   file:///home/holyblackcat/.downloads Загрузки
   ```
5. Выходим из системы, заходим обратно, и удаляем папки со старыми именами, если они откуда-то появились.

Comment: на первом шаге оно спросит - ответить "оставить как есть"

Comment: @eri Это про что он должен спросить?

Comment: xdg-user-dirs-update спрашивает нужно ли переименовать папки при смене локали